# Avoid hardcoding iPhone screen size with programmatic view creation

Tags: iphone, uiview

I was looking up how to create a view programmatically and found the following example code:

`self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];`

This works great, except I don't like that it hardcodes the size of the screen. Is there a way to look up the size of the screen? An important point someone brought up is that if the app is running during a phone call then the screen will be slightly smaller because of the green  "return to call" bar.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there a way to look up the size of
>   the screen?

Yup:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

> applicationFrame
>
> This property
>   contains the screen bounds minus the
>   area occupied by the status bar, if it
>   is visible. Using this property is the
>   recommended way to retrieve your
>   application’s initial window size. The
>   rectangle is specified in points.

Answer (score 3):

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` or 
`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`

should be all you need to get the full screen size.

I've only used the applicationFrame version myself.

(I also suggested `[UIHardware fullScreenApplicationContentRect]` but that was from some very old code - don't use it)

Comment: UIHardware is not a class in the current SDK.